# JavaFx Number Conversion

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a school assignment using JavaFx. The assignment is to create a program that converts between decimal, hex, and binary numbers using the JavaFx GUI. The GUI has 3 fields one for decimal, hex, and binary. You're supposed to enter a number in anyone of the fields and press enter and it will give you the conversions in the corresponding textfields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Exercise16_05 extends Application {
    private TextField tfDecimal = new TextField();
    private TextField tfHex = new TextField();
    private TextField tfBinary = new TextField();       

    @Override
    // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        // Create UI
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Decimal: "), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(tfDecimal, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Hex: "), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(tfHex, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Binary"), 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(tfBinary, 1, 2);

        // Create the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise 16_05");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        tfDecimal.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode()== KeyCode.ENTER) {              // When ENTER is pressed

                int decimal = Integer.parseInt(tfDecimal.getText());
                String decToHex = Integer.toHexString(decimal);
                String decToBi = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);

                tfBinary.setText(String.format(decToBi));
                tfHex.setText(String.format(decToHex));

            }
        });

        tfHex.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode()== KeyCode.ENTER) {

                int hex = Integer.parseInt(tfHex.getText(), 16); // Get data from text field
                String hexToDec = Integer.toString(hex);
                String hexToBi = Integer.toBinaryString(hex);

                 // Display hex to Bi and hex to Dec
                tfBinary.setText(String.format(hexToBi));
                tfDecimal.setText(hexToDec);

            }
        });

        tfBinary.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

                int binary = Integer.parseInt(tfBinary.getText(),2);
                String biToHex = Integer.toHexString(binary);
                 String biToDec = Integer.toString(binary);
                // String biToDec = Integer.parseInt(binary);

                tfHex.setText(String.format(biToHex));
                tfDecimal.setText(biToDec);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, sorry I just saw that I didn't have a main method with launch(args); Sorry I was to quick to pull the trigger. I've been burning the candles at both ends.

Comment: Javafx doesn't need a main method to execute, unless you are using an IDE which needs a `main()`